# Add custom generator to spaCy's class

Tags: python, class, generator, spacy

I'm having a hard time adding a generator to spaCy's `Token` class.

First, a generic Python equivalent of what I'm trying to do, which works as expected.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

@property
def lower_int_generator(self):
    x = 0
    while x < self.n:
        yield x
        x += 1

Foo.lower_ints = lower_int_generator
a = Foo(5)
print(type(a.lower_ints)) # <class 'generator'>
[x for x in a.lower_ints] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now in spaCy, which provides a `set_extension` method (see [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes)).

```
@property
def letter_generator(self):
    for x in self.text:
        yield x

spacy.tokens.token.Token.set_extension('letters', default=letter_generator, force=True)
doc = nlp('Hello world')
print(type(doc[0]._.letters)) # <class 'property'>
[x for x in doc[0]._.letters] # TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable
```

Notably, spaCy uses `@property` in its own [code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L485) and it works just fine. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `default` attribute is the value which is returned when neither `getter` nor `setter` is set hence that's what was returned (property or function if you remove the `property` decorator). You can store some static information this way.

You want to set `getter` as you did in you answer as this is the operation which is called when you want to get the value of attribute. `setter` would have to be created when changing the value, like this:

```
doc[0]._.letters = "A"
```

`setter` would be good to provide other value than `default`, though I haven't used that approach so far.

Finally, I have found a clean way of extending `spacy` (and IMO more readable than the one presented), example of `lemmatization` extension:

```
class Lemmatizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lemmatizer = spacy.lemmatizer.Lemmatizer(
            spacy.lang.en.LEMMA_INDEX,
            spacy.lang.en.LEMMA_EXC,
            spacy.lang.en.LEMMA_RULES,
        )

    def __call__(self, token):
        corrected = token._.text
        if token.text == corrected:
            return token.lemma_
        return self.lemmatizer(corrected, token.pos_)[0]

spacy.tokens.Token.set_extension("lemma", getter=Lemmatizer(), force=True)
```

As you can see, the only thing one has to use is the `__call__` overloaded method (no need for generator, but you could use it as well, depending on context of your task).

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't yet comprehend, getting rid of `@property` and using the `getter` keyword instead of `default` works.

```
def letter_generator(self):
    for x in self.text:
        yield x

spacy.tokens.token.Token.set_extension('letters', getter=letter_generator, force=True)
doc = nlp('Hello world')
print(type(doc[0]._.letters)) # <class 'generator'>
[x for x in doc[0]._.letters] # ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your generic example, you access the property via a class attribute, which means the descriptor protocol is triggered.

`set_extension`, on the other hand, simply saves a reference to the `property` object in a `dict`, which means when you access it, the descriptor protocol is *not* triggered, and you get the `property` itself, not the result of the getter.

In your workaround, you aren't using a property at all, so you get the generator function directly.